# Modificação de campo requerido se checkbox for selecionado em Django

Tags: python, django

Preciso verificar se um botão "checkbox", chamado de yes_no, foi selecionado na minha página html e modificar o campo "name" para obrigatório quando esse checkbox for acionado.
Meu código é o seguinte:

No arquivo models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class RandomModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    shirt_size = models.IntegerField()
    yes_no = models.BooleanField()
```

No arquivo forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import RandomModel


class RandomForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = RandomModel
        fields = ['name', 'shirt_size', 'yes_no']
```

No arquivo views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import *
from django.shortcuts import redirect

# Create your views here.


def random_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RandomForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('learn:random')

    else:
        form = RandomForm()
    return render(request, 'learn/index.html', {'form': form})
```

No arquivo index.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<form action="{% url 'learn:random' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.name }}
    {{ form.shirt_size }}
    {{ form.yes_no }}
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu formulário o campo `name`  está como não obrigatório mas seu modelo não irá permitir ser salvo com o campo `name` em branco, se deseja permitir isso defina no campo `name` do seu modelo `blank=True`.

Quando você herda de `forms.Form` ou de `forms.ModelForm` como é no seu caso, isso lhe permite a definição de alguns métodos no seu formulário que irão fazer uma validação digamos mais `"personalizada"` do que as que o `Django` já faz nos campos definidos,  como se a entrada é válida ou seu tamanho.

Para isso basta definir métodos no seu formulário com a seguinte assinatura:

```
def clean_<field_name>(self):
    field = self.cleaned_data['<field_name'>]
    ... # Faça aqui sua validações
    return field
```

Onde `<field_name>` é o nome do campo do seu formulário, você tem alguns passos a seguir na sua validação que é pegue o campo que deseja validar, faça suas validações em caso de falha eleve uma exceção `forms.ValidationError` em caso de sucesso retorne o campo referente ao método em questão (Isso é necessário para que o `Django` continue validando os outros dados. No seu caso você quer verificar se o campo `yes_no` for selecionado o campo name se torne obrigatório logo podemos fazer algo assim:

```
from django import forms
from .models import RandomModel


class RandomForm(forms.ModelForm):

    name = forms.CharField(required=False)

    def clean_yes_no(self):
        yes_no = self.cleaned_data['yes_no']
        if yes_no:
            if not self.cleaned_data['name']:
                raise forms.ValidationError('O campo nome é obrigatório')
        return yes_no

    class Meta:
        model = RandomModel
        fields = ['name', 'shirt_size', 'yes_no']
```

Exemplo básico de template do formulário:

```
<form action="{% learn:random %}" method="post" novalidate>{% csrf_token %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        <div>
            {{ error }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div>
                {{ error }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <div>
            {{ field.label_tag }}
            {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Comment: Funcionou corretamente, entretanto o erro de validação 'O campo nome é obrigatório' não apareceu quando apliquei meu formulário.

Comment: Seu template não está renderizando os erros dos campos.

Comment: Tudo certo agora!

Comment: Conseguiu renderizar os erros ??

Comment: Consegui, foi só incluir o código {{ form.yes_no.errors }} no meu template que o erro apareceu! Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Acabei de fazer um teste com outro código, estou recebendo um erro do tipo KeyError at /profile/config. Fiz exatamente a mesma coisa, você saberia explicar o motivo?

Comment: Poderia postar o erro completo pra mim dar uma olhada ?

Comment: KeyError at /profile/config
'b2c_active'

Answer (score 0):

Agora estou com o seguinte arquivo forms.py:

```
class SellsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    client = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'type': 'hidden'}))
    yn_choices = (('Sim', 'Sim'),
                  ('Não, emissão fiscal sem ERP', 'Não, emissão ERP'))
    yn = forms.CharField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=required=False)

def clean_b2c_active(self):
    b2c_active = self.cleaned_data['b2c_active']
    b2c_platform = self.cleaned_data['b2c_platform']
    print(b2c_platform)
    if b2c_active:
        if not b2c_platform:
            raise forms.ValidationError('O campo é obrigatório')
    return b2c_active

class Meta:
    model = Sells
    fields = '__all__'

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SellsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['b2c_platform'].required = False
    self.fields['b2b_platform'].required = False
    self.fields['b2b_platform2'].required = False
    self.fields['market_platform_1'].required = False
    self.fields['market_platform_2'].required = False
```

Com o erro associado:

```
KeyError at /profile/config
'b2c_active'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://192.168.25.192:8000/profile/config
Django Version: 2.0.7
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'b2c_active'
Exception Location: C:\Users\checkstore\Desktop\Checkstore\Clientes\forms.py 
in 
clean, line 62
Python Executable:  C:\Python36\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\checkstore\\Desktop\\Checkstore',
 'C:\\Users\\checkstore\\Desktop\\Checkstore',
 'C:\\Python36\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Python36\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python36\\lib',
 'C:\\Python36',
 'C:\\Users\\checkstore\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python36\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages',
 'c:\\users\\checkstore\\src\\django-extra-views',
 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm '
 '2018.1.4\\helpers\\pycharm_matplotlib_backend']
Server time:    Seg, 30 Jul 2018 17:06:07 +0000
```

Comment: O erro diz que não existe a chave `b2c_active` onde você definiu a mesma ?

Comment: Ela foi definida no arquivo models.py da seguinte maneira: b2c_active = models.BooleanField()

Comment: Está falando que o erro é no método `clean` e o mesmo é chamado quando fazemos `form.is_valid()` gostaria de ver sua view se puder.

Answer (score 0):

O arquivo views.py está assim:

```
def config_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SellsForm(request.POST, initial={'client': request.user.username})
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/profile')
    else:
        form = SellsForm(initial={'client': request.user.username})
    return render(request, 'Clientes/config.html', {'form': form})
```